# Who is this site targeting?

Tags: discussion

Who is this site targeting?   I read an answer earlier on meta about how we should ask questions that would attract "pros".

Who are the "pros" of personal finance?   What is the target audience?

Answer (score 2):

*Professionals* are certainly *part* of the audience we are trying to attract.  The target audience summary outlined in the [official area51 site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1721?phase=definition) are:

> [...] **people who want to be financially
>   literate, find ways to save money,
>   minimize taxes, invest wisely, plan
>   for retirement, etc. Also for
>   financially-savvy amateurs,
>   DIY-investors & personal finance pros.**

Admittedly, "personal finance pros" isn't very precise, but space was limited.  However, before area51 came along, [I started the proposal, informally at the SE 1.0 meta site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5751/proposal-for-a-personal-finance-and-money-se), where there was much more room to elaborate on the proposal.  Here's the "Target Audience" section from that draft of the proposal:

> **Target Audience**
>
> - Average working people looking to attain financial literacy and find
>     ways to save their money, minimize
>     their taxes (legitimately), invest
>     their savings wisely, plan for their
>     childrens' education savings, plan for
>     their retirement, etc.
> - Already financially-savvy individuals and do-it-yourself
>     investors.    *[semi-pro?]*
> - Financial planning professionals such as **Certified Financial Planners,
>     or others in the personal and
>     household finance industry e.g.
>     mortgage brokers, personal bankers,
>     debt counselors, etc. whose goal it is
>     to assist individuals / consumers with
>     financial planning, products, or
>     services.**    *[added emphasis]*
>
> [...]

But, that was a draft, and community input is welcome.  I've made this answer community wiki, in case anybody wants to expand on or better describe the target audience description.

Comment: The third bullet seems to be people paid to work with finances.  I'm not sure if I've seen questions from the third category nor exactly how to encourage those questions.  Any thoughts?

Comment: There have been a few *answers* from some people in that category, but no questions that I know of, yet.